# Getting cell pointer from section and row at tableView

Tags: objective-c

I have a section and a row for my tableView , i need to create a pointer to that cell so i can than edit him

I have something like this :

```
NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
 UITableViewCell* swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
```

but the indexPath now is according to some touch location, i want to create it with a given section and row .

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for get the index path using section and row use this `NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:<rowIndex> inSection:<sectionIndex>]`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:<rowIndex> inSection:<sectionIndex>]
UITableViewCell* swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
```

Simple as that..:)